# Compiler of XSLT to C#

Tags: c#, xslt

I am taking part in a project where I got to write a program which takes as an input XSLT file and return proper C# code. Besides It is really something new for me I don't know how to get started. Could anyone give me some prompts how to strike up with this project?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please describe more clear the project ?

Comment: I got to make a program which takes a xslt file and returns c# file for the xslt. The problem is I don't know how to start processing xslt to obtain proper c# code.

Comment: Please write example of input and output of the program

Answer (score 2):

Well Microsoft has [xsltc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399405.aspx) to compile a stylesheet to a .NET assembly. You could use a tool like [Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to decompile the assembly to C# code.